# firebase analytics empty IOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

i have created a flutter app and i am using firebase services.
I am having problems with the analytics data from ios, I cannot see the connected users, in android the problem does not occur. Currently my application is in beta on testflight.
The application is developed in flutter, as can be seen from the image the dau part of ios is 0. how can resolve this? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementation. Few points to note

1. Have you added the right google services.plist file through xcode.
2. Check info.plist if you added the reverse client id in url scheme
3. Check if you have not added any condition to initialise firebase in the app.